# Showing UITabBar in a separate view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I'm new to Xcode/Cocoa/Objective-C, and I need a little help.

Essentially, I'm working on an app in which the first window has a couple of buttons; this is the Main Menu. When pressed, a button opens up a separate view that has a UITabBar and a Navigation Bar at the top that leads back to the Main Menu.

My two questions:

1. How do you make a UITabBar appear only in certain views?
2. How do you create a button to switch between nib files and not only views?

I've been using a RootViewController and TabBarController classes to be used by my RootView.xib (which is the main menu that holds the buttons) and a couple .xib files for the tab bar views (one nib file has each of the two views for the tab bars and nav bar).

I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

present your view with buttons modaly in your appDelegate. When you dismiss this view set a view controller with setSelectedViewController: as rootController in your TabBarControllers array.

Hope this helps